# What is the derivative of, $x e^{\ln(x^2)}$

Tags: calculus

Would substitution be helpful? That's the only thing I can think of but then I'm not sure how to derive $\ln(x^2)$

Comment: Do you know the product and chain rules? Also, note that $$\ln(x^2) = 2 \ln x$$

Comment: Is that a $(\ln x)^2$ or a $\ln(x^2)$?

Comment: just the x is squared

Comment: People should be careful here if we are going to be technical, because it's _not_ true that $e^{\ln\left(x^2\right)} = x^2$ when $x = 0$.  At this point the function $f(x) = e^{\ln\left(x^2\right)}$ is undefined...it's a removable discontinuity, but you have to state that fact.  And it's _especially_ not true that $\ln\left(x^2\right) = 2\ln(x)$ when $x < 0$.  To make that true you have to say $\ln\left(x^2\right) = 2\ln\left|x\right|, x \neq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

$e^{\ln(anything)} = anything$, i.e., exponention and log are inverses. So the thing you need to differentiate is just
$$
x \cdot x^2 = x^3.
$$
I'll bet you can differentiate that.

Comment: Jared's point is a good one; my answer is correct for $x \ne 0$. I'm guessing (given that the OP didn't know how to handle even this case) that the author intended that restriction, since most beginning calculus books tend to implicitly say that the domain of a function is "all the things you can legally plug in" (or something like that).

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}xe^{\ln x^2}&=\frac{d}{dx}x\cdot x^2 & \text{because } e^{\ln x^2}=x^2\\
&= \frac{d}{dx} x^3 & \text{exponent law: } x\cdot x^2 = x^{1+2}=x^3\\
&=3x^2 & \text{use power rule: } \frac{d}{dx} x^3=3x^{3-1}=3x^2
\end{align}

Comment: what about when $x = 0$?

Comment: @Jared The domain of the $\ln$ function excludes negative numbers including $0$.

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع Then it's not true that $\frac{d}{dx}\left(xe^{\ln\left(x^2\right)}\right) = 3x^2$  ($0$ should be explicitly left out).  Also the original function can handle negative $x$ (assuming only real values--of course if you allow complex values then negatives are fine--only zero gives a problem).

Comment: @Jared $e^{\ln x^2}=x^2\,\color{grey}\forall x\in\mathbb R-\{0\}$, since $x^2>0$ in that domain. I didn't pay attention to see that there was a square in the $\ln$ function.